# C# foreach loop skipping some values during iteration

Tags: sql, arrays, string, multi-select

I have a multi-select control whereby I need to commit all items selected to SQL Server table. When I submit the form only 1 item is getting committed even though when i inspect using Step Debugger all the selected values are indeed populated in variable employeees4 (attached image). i have observed that only the first item in the selection is getting committed. Any help on what i could possibly be missing?

Please note that i have used slightly different variable name in attached image has  i.e year instead of employeees4,  but the code is the same .

I am getting selected items as below :

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewOverTimeRequest(FormCollection formcollection)
    {

        Models.Employee.OverTimeRequest request = new Models.Employee.OverTimeRequest();
         try
        {

            var batch = new OvertimeBatch();
            request.employees = GetEmployees();

            request.EmployeeNumber = new string[] { Convert.ToString(formcollection["EmployeeNumber"]) };
            var employeees1= request.EmployeeNumber.Split(',');                
            string[] employeees2 = employeees.SingleOrDefault().ToArray();
            string employeees3 = Helpers.ConvertStringArrayToString( employeees2);
            string[] employeees4 =employeees3.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach ( string emp in employeees4)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Helpers.DatabaseConnect))
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SubmitOverTime", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNum", emp);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateDone", DateTime.Now);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
                  return RedirectToAction("OverTime");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return View(request);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("OverTime");

       }
}
```

Model :

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Employee ")]
    public string[] EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> employees { get; set; }
```

[image: StepDebugger]

Comment: So for the attached request only the value mihr22 is being committed to the database

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: Next candidate then is that your stored proc is not doing what you expect it to. Can you show us that?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you If condition to below.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = New SqlConnection(Helpers.DatabaseConnect))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = New SqlCommand("SubmitOverTime", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpNum", SqlDbType.varchar(max));
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateDone", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        foreach(String emp In employeees4)
        {
           cmd.Parameters["@FixtureId"].Value=emp;
           cmd.Parameters["@FixtureId"].Value= DateTime.Now;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("OverTime");
}
```